# Paypal android checkout sdk gives invalid scope in live mode

Tags: android, paypal

I am developing an android application which includes in-app Paypal payments for buying coins.
I am using the official sdk https://github.com/paypal/android-checkout-sdk  with latest version 0.3.0.
I am facing the following error when clicking Paypal Button in LIVE mode
[image]

I have the following configuration in my code

```
val environment: Environment = if (resources.getBoolean(R.bool.production)) Environment.LIVE else Environment.SANDBOX
val config = CheckoutConfig(
      this,
      getString(R.string.paypal_client_id), environment,
      "by.the.way://paypalpay", CurrencyCode.USD, UserAction.PAY_NOW,
      SettingsConfig(
                true,
                false
     )
)
setConfig(config)
```

This is the code for buying coins:

```
btnPaymentPayPal.setup(object : CreateOrder {
            override fun create(createOrderActions: CreateOrderActions) {
                val purchaseUnits = ArrayList<PurchaseUnit>()
                purchaseUnits.add(
                        PurchaseUnit.Builder()
                                .amount(
                                        Amount.Builder()
                                                .currencyCode(CurrencyCode.USD)
                                                .value(coinsPakageModel.price.toString())
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .description(coinsPakageModel.name)
                                .build()
                )
                val order: Order = Order.Builder().appContext(
                        AppContext.Builder()
                                .userAction(UserAction.PAY_NOW)
                                .build()
                ).intent(OrderIntent.CAPTURE)
                        .purchaseUnitList(purchaseUnits).build()
                createOrderActions.create(order)
            }
        },
                object : OnApprove {
                    override fun onApprove(approval: Approval) {
                        approval.orderActions.capture(object : OnCaptureComplete {
                            override fun onCaptureComplete(result: captureOrderResult) {
                              //...
                            }
                        })
                    }
                },
                object : OnCancel {
                    override fun onCancel() {
                        //...
                    }
                },
                object : OnError {
                    override fun onError(errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
                        //...
                    }
                }
        )
```

And this is my Paypal Configuration in developers dashboard. My account is a business account :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Finally I got fixed my problem, you need enable email in live mode, but first you need to pass the paypal review process.

Comment: I already resolved the problem by enabling Email and Full name. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was trying to get Paypal integration to work in PRODUCTION mode, so you need enable email and full name in live mode, but first you need to pass the paypal review process.

Comment: How should i do that?